# Removing temp files from unity project on device

Tags: unity-game-engine, temp

The issue is that I closed down the unity editor while it was transferring files to my device (android samsung s9).  This left a set of temp files on the device which I cannot delete because I don't know how to access them.  These temp files are causing the following error in the unity editor:

```
    IOException: Failed to Copy File / Directory from 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.13f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\Data\unity default resources' to 'Temp/StagingArea/Data\unity default resources': destination path already exists.
UnityEditor.FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory (System.String source, System.String dest) (at <480b5a3bd3214ce5831f6dd8c68fdc55>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.PrepareUnityResources.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <3167064085404657b0d6c498207da025>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <3167064085404657b0d6c498207da025>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <3167064085404657b0d6c498207da025>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <3167064085404657b0d6c498207da025>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <480b5a3bd3214ce5831f6dd8c68fdc55>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

How do I delete those temp files so that I can use my device with unity?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of "device" this is? (Android, iOS, soda machine etc.) different kind of devices will store temp in different places, although on most occasions a simple restart should clear any `temp` folders stored. So for now i'll stick with the go-to question of "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" ^^

Comment: Ok - it's a android (samsung s9).  I've just restarted the phone and came up with the same error.

Comment: What happens if you clear the app's cache? (Go to your app > App info > Storage > Clear data/Clear Cache). This should clean up any additional files (Note stuff like save files, config files etc will also get wiped or reset to their "fresh install" state along with any temp files)

Comment: It turned out that the temp folder was still on the computer's hard drive, not on the phone.  I did try clearing the cache (had no effect).  I've removed the temp folder in the project folder on HDD and just recompiling now.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that the temp folder was within the project folder, not the device.  By restarting unity I managed to get it to compile and install on phone successfully.